# How to show "connection error" page?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Maybe, It's a noobie question but I cannot make a good solution. 

**Problem**

For example: I have a some fragment that send some HTTPS-request. And at this moment user's device loses the Internet connection. In the most part of apps it shows page to user with message "Internet connection failed... bla-bla... and e.g. button 'Try again'". And when device restores the Internet connection then it returns the source fragment and continues loading.

My app using fragments to represent some page of server so it can have a lot of opened fragments.

**My ways of solution**

I can write a special fragment (ConnectionFailedFragment) to show this page. But then I cannot understand how to return control to source fragment then device restores the Internet connection. And make this source fragment transparent to the user. To he cannot return to the source fragment only in the previous that was loaded already (see stack example below).

**Stack sample**

1. First fragment **[loaded]**
2. Second fragment **[loaded]**
3. Previous fragment **[loaded]**
4. Source fragment (must be transparent for user back navigation) **[wait loading]**
5. Connection failed fragment (must return the control to the previous fragment when device restores the Internet connection). **[wait connection]**

All fragments may be an instance of any class (I have different fragment classes for different server page).

Has any ideas? Or maybe has this problem another good solutions?

Comment: You could gather some ideas from other apps.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't know an another app with open source code.

Comment: Can you post link, please?

Comment: Does the no connection screen needs to be a separate fragment? If you take a look at Gmail, for instance, it just shows a SnackBar notifying the user about the lack of connection. Moving user from screen to screen automatically usually results in a bad experience.

Comment: You don't need open source. I was just saying look at Gmail or Facebook or Whatsapp or Instagram, for example, for ideas

Comment: It isn't my choice,  just I have task where it needs to show (with specified design)

Comment: But thank you for solution sample. If it haven't solution that I need then I'll call to the customer to change design.

Comment: You could actually use a custom `Dialog`as you'd a "loading animation" and auto-dismiss it if the connection gets re-established. Have you already considered doing this?

Comment: Thank you! You very helped me! I think a full screen dialogue suits for it.